# ¿Cómo resuelvo este error CS0119 en C#?

Tags: c#, unity

Intentando aprender sobre Unity, me encontré con este error que surge al intentar usar las físicas y no encuentro solución al mismo.

Acá la parte con el error y el código:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        object value = gameObject.GetComponent.Rigidbody2D().AddForce(new Vector2(-1000f * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent.Rigidbody2D().AddForce(new Vector2(1000f * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega todo el código de ese script y señala claramente en que línea marca ese error (puedes colocar un comentario arriba de esa línea)